# Django translations in Javascript files

Tags: javascript, django, language-translation

I followed the Django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/#using-the-javascript-translation-catalog) to internalize the js files, but it does not work. Here's my setup:

settings.py:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),)
```

urls.py in root project:

```
from django.views.i18n import JavaScriptCatalog
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('jsi18n/', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
)
```

Running the following commands inside the folder and the .po and .mo files were generated:

```
django-admin makemessages -l pt_BR

django-admin makemessages -d djangojs -l pt_BR

django-admin makemessages -a

django-admin compilemessages
```

django.po file:

```
msgid "Customer"
msgstr "Cliente"
```

In the html template use as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>

console.log( gettext('Customer') );
```

Nothing happens, the text continues in English. Does anyone know what can it be?

Comment: Are you sure your current language is not english?

Comment: Hello! I have `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br' ` in my settings.py. I deleted the .po and .mo files, recreated these files, included the translation and compiled. Even though the translation does not work, the output of the text continues in English.

Comment: Now I can show the translation in the html template, but the output of the javascript remains in English. I put the path this way.
`LOCALE_PATHS = [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'locale')] `

Comment: Or using the default path and each app will need to have a locale folder.
`LOCALE_PATHS = [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "locale")] `

Comment: Same problem there, and still investigating

Comment: is this fixed in django 3? still having this problem in django 2.2.7

Comment: Still the same issue with Django 3.2.x. Have spent a lot of time with it, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I have resolved this issue. For some reason (feature?), Django compiles the JS translations into `[project-folder]/locale` and not `[your-app]/locale`. So, to make it work, copy the `djangojs.mo` file over to `[your-app]/locale` and see if it works for you. Did the job for me.

I've tried various parameters in `urls.py` and elsewhere but I cannot make Django compile the trans file right where it belongs.